# How can I make my mouseup and mousedown functions work with touchscreen phones?

Tags: javascript, mobile, canvas, touch

I have a canvas square over a background image, the idea is users can use it as a lottery ticket style scratcher. Currently users can use the mouse and click over the canvas to erase the square and this works. However when I try to touch the canvas in a mobile browser, the erase tool does not work and all I do is move the browser around.

Here is the code.

```
    (function() {
    // Creates a new canvas element and appends it as a child
    // to the parent element, and returns the reference to
    // the newly created canvas element


    function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
        var canvas = {};
        canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
        canvas.node.width = width || 100;
        canvas.node.height = height || 100;
        parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
        return canvas;
    }

    function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
        var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
        var ctx = canvas.context;
        // define a custom fillCircle method
        ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
            this.fillStyle = fillColor;
            this.beginPath();
            this.moveTo(x, y);
            this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 3, false);
            this.fill();
        };
        ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
            ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        };
        ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "#ddd");

        // bind mouse events
        canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
               return;
            }
            var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            var radius = 20; // or whatever
            var fillColor = '#ff0000';
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);



        };
        canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = true;
        };
        canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = false;
        };



    }

    var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    init(container, 274, 308, '#ddd');

})();
```

Comment: Try e.stopPropagation(); ?

Comment: Where would e.stopPropagation(); go?

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas is only listening to mouse events. You should bind the browsers touch event too. Depends on the mobile browser it the way you do that it may be a little bit different. Here are some good resources you can start with:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `touchstart` ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart)) and `touchend` ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend)) events.

Be aware that the pageX and pageY of these can be a little tricky.

Here is a function I have used in the past to get these coordinates across the browsers - even mobile Safari. Just pass in the event to this to get the coordinates more reliably if you have trouble with them.

```
function getPageXAndY(evt) {
    var pageX = evt.pageX;
    if (!pageX) {
        if (evt.originalEvent && evt.originalEvent.touches) {
            pageX = evt.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        }
        else if (evt.touches && evt.touches.length > 0) {
            pageX = evt.touches[0].pageX;
        }
    }
    var pageY = evt.pageY;
    if (!pageY) {
        if (evt.originalEvent && evt.originalEvent.touches) {
            pageY = evt.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
        }
        else if (evt.touches && evt.touches.length > 0) {
            pageY = evt.touches[0].pageY;
        }
    }

    return [pageX, pageY];
};
```

Called like:

```
canvas.node.ontouchend = function(e) {
    pageCoords = getPageXAndY(e); // returns [pageXVal, pageYVal]
    ...
}
```

Comment: My `getPageXAndY` function would go on the same level as `function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {...}`. To match the other functions you could define it as `function getPageXAndY(evt) {...}` -- I've changed my code there to make it clearer.

Comment: If that helped you, please accept this answer so it's clear for people asking similar questions in future :)